# Filter a view by user-created tags in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I'd like to add a block to the user profile that shows them content listings in their groups based on tags that they have in their profile.

(ie: someone puts a bike up for sale, the user has listed "bike" on their wishlist, it should show up to get their attention)

Since these tags vary user-to-user, I'm not sure exactly how to set up the filter.

Going a little farther, can I sort them by the number of matching tags?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that taxonomy terms and views can be very tricky to get right. The main problems is that taxonomy terms has a one to many relationship with nodes, and views is built to be generic.

It might be quicker to create such a block in a custom module instead, because you may very well get stuck in views before getting what you want. Also you most likely have to create your own sort plugin for views, to get the sorting you want. I haven't seen any module creating something like that, and I don't think it's possible with views core. Creating plugin for views can be very harry, the first time you do it, so unless you know your way around views, I think you will have more luck just creating a block yourself. It's much simpler, than having to extend the views functionality.

Comment: well damn. I suck at php, so that sounds like a recipe for seppuku to me. =/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)? You can set up a block with views that retrieves (almost) *ANY* information from the database.

In your case, you can filter the information that you need and that belongs to the current user, also, sorting is doable via the Views administration.

Comment: yes, I'm using views. The problem is that I need to be able to tell views to grab "user tags" and use them as a filter on the results. It's a dynamic filter, not a set one. So far, I've been unable to figure this out.

To be clear, it's not user-defined at the time of the querie. It needs to be retrieved from the tags that are set in their profile.

Example: the user tags their profile with "car, truck, rollerskates"... then I want a Views block on the profile that pulls the results from the site that include one or more of their tags, providing relevant content.